# how to get the values from ngStorage

Tags: json, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

How to get local stored json value from browser using ng stroage module in angularjs

i use `$scope.data = $localStorage.notes;`

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 well">
  {{data}}
 </div>
```

but json values are getting i want only text values

**[Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/QIEXAD/)**

Comment: did you check some of the links about it? https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/use-ngstorage-angularjs-local-storage-needs/ or https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/angularjs-game-using-ngstorage-local-storage

Comment: @trainoasis i checked teamtreehouse but their plunker is not working

Comment: @trainoasis i get the json values but i want only the text values from the json data . i updated my plunker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want text values then get them using `.` notation

```
        <div class="col-xs-6 well">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li data-ng-repeat="item in data">

                <span class="h1">id:{{ item.id }} age:{{ item.age }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7evMCL?p=preview)

Comment: @kachalimbu  will please say how to remove one item in local json value ?

Comment: @gjramanaa please add new question for it. I can't type longer code snippet in the comments here.

Comment: i want to remove the value when i click the remove button please check this plunker 

 http://embed.plnkr.co/HG3Ki15JoVBRG9wCy0nd/preview

Comment: you were almost there. Here is updated plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/gITKkJ34ICS44CCnu7Gr?p=preview

Comment: i want to increment a value and decrement a value can you help this i post the separate question here is a plunker    
http://embed.plnkr.co/cfPbG5/preview